# Electronics Circuits Simulator Framework?

Tags: programming, simulation, library

Is there a framework for circuits simulation that I can use through easy APIs? and return me an array of results for each component?

I want to build an android based simulator, so a java framework would be perfect, is there any advice?

Comment: One possibility would be to make a wrapper for the good old SPICE and parse its output. If you really want Java, you could take a look at [Falstad Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/), but I'm not sure of its license and how easy it would be to call it externally. I think they used it for iCircuit.

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap SPICE and call it in android? has any one done this before?

Comment: I don't see why not. You'll have to compile SPICE for ARM (you may have to experiment a bit with compiler settings to get the widest amount of supported processors) and then call it from your GUI, which isn't all that complicated. What would be a bit complex is to write a program that will actually generate scripts for SPICE and then show results in a nice way.

Comment: AndrejaKo, would you be interested to accomplish it as a freelance project? (the SPICE calling side, I will do my own gui to show results) I've searched for your email, but I couldn't find it :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'll have to refuse. Your offer does sound extremely tempting, but I can't accept it for several reasons. First: I don't have any experience with mobile phone application development in general and even less with Android in particular (I'm still using a Symbian phone), second I don't have much experience making SPICE net-lists, since I've always used it through wrappers.

Comment: These two lead to the third (and in my opinion greatest) reason: I don't have much time at the moment, since I have exams coming, so I'll be busy for a while. As a result of that, I won't be able to learn the needed tool-set to actually develop a program. As for the e-mail, should you ever wish to contact me, you can do that via my SourceForge page for example.

Comment: Its fine Andre, I hope you success in your studying, I didn't find your email at SourceForge either .. would recommend any developer, I will be glad to hear from you ..